# How To Access Custom Variable in Smarty Template in WHMCS Email

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

I am struggling to access a custom variable I a setting when I use the WHMCS API to send an email...
Please see the API command below, aswell as the smarty tag I am using to try and display the array.

I have tried several different methods but cannot access the array I defined...

Any Assistance would be much appreciated :).

**API Command**

```
$results = localAPI("SendEmail", ['messagename'=>'My Email Template', 'id'=>$client->userid, 'customvars' => ['myvariables' => ['test_var_1'=>'value 1', 'test_var_2'=>'value 2']]]);
```

**Smarty Template Syntax I Tried**

```
{foreach from=$myvariables item=custom_field}
   {$custom_field.test_var_1}
{/foreach}
```

I am receiving nothing though in the email... I also tried

```
{foreach from=$client_custom_fields.myvariables item=custom_field}
    {$custom_field.test_var_1}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the smarty debug tag and then view the email in the email message log to see exactly where the variable is being sent. Just add:

```
{debug}
```

To the body if your template.